# How can I convert shadow angle and depth into an HTML5 canvas shadowOffset representation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to convert a given angle and depth for a shadow into an html5 canvas shadowOffset representation.

For example:

```
var angle = 90;
var depth = 10;
```

should return shadow offsets as follows:

```
context.shadowOffsetX = 10;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
```

and if...

```
var angle = 135;
var depth = 15;
```

then the shadow offsets should be:

```
context.shadowOffsetX = 15;
context.shadowOffsetY = 15;
```

While I am certain that this is a simple mathematical calculation, i truly have no idea where to begin.  Therefore I am unable to post what I have tried so far.  Math really is not my strong point.

If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple :

```
var angleInRad = angle * 2 * Math.PI / 360 ;
context.shadowOffsetX = depth * Math.cos(angleInRad) ;
context.shadowOffsetY = depth * Math.sin(angleInRad) ;
```

You might want to use Math.trunc on the offsets.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thank you ever so much.  Although I can see now that it is indeed quite simple.  For me, and my mathematically stupid brain.  It really was not.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. I believe that people not understanding Math has to do with the -so cold- way it is teached, but maybe this is not the place to discuss this topic :-) Happy coding.

Comment: You can simplify the first line to: `var angleInRad = angle * Math.PI / 180;` (and an awesome few CPU cycles are saved! :-) ).